# Registration manual MAC Address

Tags: linux, debian, mac-address, arp

```
arp  ether  –i  eth0  -s 10.252.108.143 00:24:e8:08:a2:ad
```

ether:unknow host

what sould I do? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`sudo arp -t ether -i eth0 -s 10.252.108.143 00:24:e8:08:a2:ad`